# How are all 613 mitzvot dependent on one mitzvah?

Tags: tefilla, mitzvah

There is a line said before donning the tzitzit, talit and the tefillin, and the shaking of the lulav which reads (text adapted from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Jewish_prayers_and_blessings and I don't know if there are variants and translation from the Artscroll siddur)

> יהי רצון מלפניך ה׳ א‑להי וא‑להי אבותי, שתהא חשובה מצות _____ לפניך כאלו קימתיה בכל פרטיה ודקדוקי וכונותיה ותריג מצות התלוים בה, אמן סלה.‏
>
> May it be Your will, Hashem, my God and he God of my forefathers, the commandment of ______ be as worthy before You as if I had fulfilled it in all details, implications, and intentions, as well as the six hundred thirteen commandments that are dependent upon it. Amen, Selah!

In what sense are the taryag mitzvot dependent on the putting on of tallit, tzitzit and tefillin or shaking the lulav?

Note -- I don't know if the same formulation is said before the performance of other mitzvot but maybe knowing "why" there is dependence might help me anticipate other situations in which it is said or why it isn't.

Comment: A few Mitzvot are listed as being as valuable as all the Mitzvot (Tzitzit, Talmud Torah, etc.). Probably not to be taken litereally.

Comment: are you sure that in this context teluim bahh should be translated by dependent?

Comment: @kouty It isn't my translation. What would you rather it mean?

Comment: I looked at your link, and (perhaps it has changed since you first wrote the question) it looks like the Yehi Ratzon is only tied to Tzitzit. If the question is limited to Tzitzit, it's a little easier to answer (similar to how @WAF answers in the first part of his answer). Is there a source that ties this Yehi Ratzon to other mitzvs as well?

Comment: in my siddur tefillah hashalem (Greenwald) the yehi ratzon for tallit, tzitzit, lulav, and tefillin have it.

Comment: Could this be why the halakha and custom is ETRG 604, 3 Avot, 3 Aravot, and (3+1) tefach Lulab?  because equals 613

Answer (score 3):

The example of *tzitzis* does stand out as being a gateway *mitzva* to the fulfillment of the others. *Tzitzis* is commanded initially as a mnemonic tool to spur one on to performance of all other *mitzvos* in *B'midbar* 15:39.

- > וְהָיָה לָכֶם לְצִיצִת, וּרְאִיתֶם אֹתוֹ וּזְכַרְתֶּם אֶת כָּל מִצְו‍ֹת ה' וַעֲשִׂיתֶם אֹתָם
- Step 1: Have *tzitzis*.
- Step 2: Look at them.
- Step 3: Recall all *mitzvos*.
- Step 4: Do them!

*T'filin* may have a more direct link to other *mitzva* performance<sup>1</sup>, but they trivially serve as a facilitator therefor by being lifetime extenders according to a statement by *Resh Lakish* in *M'nachos* 44.

- > כל המניח תפילין מאריך ימים
- Many have commented on how they uniquely might help lengthen one's life.

**On the other hand**, maybe it doesn't matter that some *mitzvos* are more prominently catalysts, and the dependency idea applies equally to all of them<sup>2</sup>. *S'fas Emes* (at the top of *Chayei Sara* 5632) suggests such a thing based on a holistic view of the *mitzvos* which, together and only together, form one cohesive body. Extending the body analogy, he points out that the limbs of a human depend on each other in the sense that each is only contributing to the whole if the rest of the whole is present to be contributed to.<sup>3</sup>

Applying this understanding to the pre-*mitzva* passage in question, the *S'fas Emes* allegedly answered the question of why the line is not "as well as the six hundred *twelve* commandments that are dependent upon it" by saying that it's really talking about the monolithic complement - or "body" - of *mitzvos* and not the discrete list of items.

---

<sup>1</sup>The *Imrei Emes* (at the end of *B'reshis* of 5669) deals with *tzitzis* and *t'filin* being correctives for temptation toward sin, as well as keys to other *mitzvos*, apparently based on *Zohar*. I would bet that his father dealt with the *lulav* similarly, considering how much effort he devoted to explaining *Sukos* and its accouterments.

<sup>2</sup>At least the proactive ones, which are relevant here.

<sup>3</sup>I don't think this is circular if you grant at least that the whole is greater than the sum of its parts.