# The difference between terms for mitzvot

Tags: tefilla, mitzvah, kavana-concentration

Before certain parts, my siddur (Tefillah Hashalem, Ashkenaz) has "[Yehi Ratzon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78441/how-are-all-613-mitzvot-dependent-on-one-mitzvah)" sections to help one prepare. These paragraphs (found AFTER the bracha for Tzitzit, but before the others) outline the mitzvah and end with the hope that through the fulfilling of these, it will be as if we have fulfilled all other mitzvot. I have found them before putting on [Tzitzit](https://books.google.com/books?id=mYotAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%90%20%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%AA&source=bl&ots=tL3k7Fs5lm&sig=DkoR_GkX12_K9gnWH7zvZHiWwQo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz08PdxebWAhXH1CYKHQiPAjIQ6AEIRzAF#v=onepage&q=%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%90%20%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%AA&f=false), Tallit, and [Tefillin](https://books.google.com/books?id=RixfAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%90%20%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA&source=bl&ots=0ibCCFKxWW&sig=u7w2_M89vDyG9S44VuUzrbK1ZuA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2orWgxubWAhXKKiYKHe48By8Q6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%90%20%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA&f=false), before taking the Arba Minim, sitting in the Sukkah. There might be [others](https://books.google.com/books?id=hJM_AAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA74&lpg=RA1-PA74&dq=%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%90%20%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA&source=bl&ots=SMM3KWocDh&sig=64fmtTUYjZb_cLvylqc2aHI4Ysc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2orWgxubWAhXKKiYKHe48By8Q6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%90%20%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA&f=false) but I haven't found them yet.

The listings of what would be fulfilled isn't the same for all the mitzvot. What is the difference between the following terms that would make some of them appropriate for one mitzvah and a different selection for another mitzvah?

prateha

dikdukeha

chavanoteha (these 3 used for Tzitzit, tallit and tefillin)

Shorasheha (with prateha, for lulav)

t'na'eha (with prateha and dikdukeha for sitting in a sukkah)